# Adjoint of a matrix and inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, adjoint-operators

As everyone know that we can use a matrix $A$ to represent an operator $T$.

The adjoint of a matrix $A$ is denoted as $A^*$, which takes complex conjugate of $A$ and then transpose.

My problem is, what is the relationship between $A^*$ and $A^{-1}$?

I mean as we know $Ax = b$, $x = A^{-1}b$. (If not emphasize on the dimension of $x$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know the dual space of a vector spaces?

Comment: If : A is unitary ($ AA^*=A^*A=I$ ) , then : $A^* = A^{-1}$

Comment: I mean like $T$ maps from $V$ to $W$ and $T^*$ maps from $W^*$ to $V^*$ so is $A$. Then what is the meaning of $A^{-1}$. It maps from where to where?

Comment: If $T:V\to W$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}$ represents $T^{-1} :W\to V$.

Comment: @sleevechen: There are two types of adjoints - Hilbert adjoint and Hermitian adjoint . I feel when you are talking of dual spaces, it refers to hilbert adjoint . But, all the calculations done using the symbol $A^*$ refer to the hermitian adjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $A^{-1}A = I$, hence $A^* (A^{-1})^* = I$, from which it follows that
$(A^*)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^*$.